# CSS changes to .menu .leaf affect main-menu AND admin shortcut menu in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

I'm using drupal 7 and have created the subtheme of omega using drush omega-wizard. I'm using compass to watch for changes to the scss files and it's +/- behaving as I'd expect. My problem occurs when I try to style the main-menu with something like:

```
.menu .leaf {
    width: 30px;
}
```

The restyling works but it also affects the admin's shortcut menu which uses .menu .leaf. Is there a setting in the config that I've missed, should I be targeting the menu in another way. How do I not affect the shortcut menu when styling the main-menu?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks, Steve

Comment: This is not a solution but you have one extra dot after leaf.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your CSS more specific so that it only applies to menu items on your main menu. You can do this by prefixing the CSS rule with the class of its container e.g.

```
.block--system-main-menu .menu .leaf. {
    width: 30px;
}
```